# Bootstrap 3 nav menu is showing first 2 list items when responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have searched high and low for the answer but to no avail. I have a sandbox website www.bluestackbrewing.com

When you resize it to mobile, the first two lists in the menu item are   showing. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you for any response.

```
<div class="row nav-menu">
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 columns">

</div>

<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 columns">
    <ul class="menu navbar-collapse">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="pages/pronorm-german-kitchens.html">Pronorm German Kitchens</a>
            <ul class="subnav">
                <li><a href="pages/y-line.html">Y-LINE</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/x-line-2.html">X-LINE</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/proline.html">PROLINE</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/classicline.html">CLASSICLINE</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="pages/bespoke-kitchens.html">BESPOKE KITCHENS</a>
        </li>


        <li><a href="pages/storage-solutions-accessories.html">STORAGE SOLUTIONS & ACCESSORIES</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="pages/contacta.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="social-icons text-right">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="icon social_twitter"></i>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="icon social_facebook"></i>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="icon social_instagram"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add some code here

Comment: Hope that helps. I appreciate your help

Comment: fix your code errors https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bluestackbrewing.com%2F

Comment: I do that last before launching. This is a sandbox site. I just want to fix the navbar and I am not sure what is wrong.